# Prove that this requirement can be met if and only if $B \in \mathcal{B}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, perturbation-theory

(a) Let $R(t, \omega)$ denote the rotation matrix
$$
R(t, \omega)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\cos (\omega t) & -\sin (\omega t) \\
\sin (\omega t) & \cos (\omega t) 
\end{array}\right] .
$$
Find a $2 \times 2$ matrix $G(\omega)$ such that $R(t, \omega)=e^{t G(\omega)}$.

(b) Set $A(t)=R(t, \omega) B[R(t, \omega)]^{-1}$ for $B \in \mathcal{B}$. Let $\dot{x}=A(t) x$ and define $y(t)=$ $[R(t, \omega)]^{-1} x(t)$. Show that
$$
\dot{y}=[B-G(\omega)] y
$$
and find the corresponding expressions for $y(t), x(t)$, for any given $x(0)$.

(c) For $$A(t)=
\begin{pmatrix}
 -1-9(\cos(6t))^2+12\sin(6t)\cos(6t) & 12(\cos(6t))^2+9\sin(6t)\cos(6t)\\
   -12(\sin(6t))^2+9\sin(6t)\cos(6t) &    -1-9(\sin(6t))^2+12\sin(6t)\cos(6t)\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

, find $B, \omega$, and the eigenvalues of $B-G(\omega)$.

(d) Based on the solution obtained in (b), to generate a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A(t)$ with negative real eigenvalues such that (1) holds, it suffices to find a $2 \times 2$ matrices $B$ and $G(\omega)$ such that there exists a nonzero vector $v$ and a $\lambda>0$ for which $[G-B(\omega)] v=\lambda v$. Prove that this requirement can be met if and only if $B \in \mathcal{B}$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the collection of matrices having negative eigenvalues s.t $xBx>0$.

My try:

a) Proof. (a) Since $R(t, \omega)$ has two complex eigenvalues, the most efficient way I can thought of is to regard it as an element of Lie group $S O(2)$, and it suffices to find the generator $X$ for the corresponding lie algebra so(2), i.e.
$$
\frac{d}{d \alpha} R(\alpha)=X R(\alpha)
$$
Then we get
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
-\sin \alpha & -\cos \alpha \\
\cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha \\
\sin \alpha & \cos \alpha
\end{array}\right]
$$
$X$ is a generator for the 1-dimensional lie algebra, so
$$
G(\omega)=\omega \cdot\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -\omega \\
\omega & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
(b) We take the derivative for $x(t)=R(t, \omega) y(t)$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
R^{\prime}(t, \omega) y(t)+R(t, \omega) \dot{y}(t) &=R(t, \omega) B y(t) \\
R(t, \omega) \dot{y}(t) &=\left[R(t, \omega) B-R^{\prime}(t, \omega)\right] y(t) \\
\dot{y}(t) &=\left[B-\left[R(t, \omega)^{-1}\right] R^{\prime}(t, \omega)\right] y(t) .
\end{aligned}
$$
It suffices to show $G(\omega)=\left[R(t, \omega)^{-1}\right] R^{\prime}(t, \omega)$ and notice that
$$
\left[R(t, \omega)^{-1}\right] R^{\prime}(t, \omega)=e^{-t G(\omega)} \cdot\left(e^{t G(\omega)} \cdot G(\omega)\right)=G(\omega) .
$$
Now we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
&y(t)=\exp [B-G(\omega)] \cdot[R(t, \omega)]^{-1} x(0) \\
&x(t)=R(t, \omega) \exp [B-G(\omega)] \cdot[R(t, \omega)]^{-1} x(0)
\end{aligned}
$$

(c) For example (2), we know $\omega=6$ and
$$
\begin{aligned}
B=[R(t, 6)]^{-1} A(t) R(t, 6) &=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\cos (6 t) & \sin (6 t) \\
-\sin (6 t) & \cos (6 t)
\end{array}\right] A(t)\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\cos (6 t) & -\sin (6 t) \\
\sin (6 t) & \cos (6 t)
\end{array}\right] \\
&=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\cos (6 t) & -\sin (6 t) \\
\sin (6 t) & \cos (6 t)
\end{array}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

**Now I am stuck with mainly d)** and partially c). Please help me if you can.

Comment: Is that supposed to be $[B-G(\omega)]v = \lambda v$?

Comment: Yes, I think I have written that. If I wrote something else. I am sorry for that